# How can I call or include skin JS file in magento1 CMS Page Layout?

Tags: javascript, xml, magento, admin, magento-1.9

I tried to include js in Layout XML of cms page but js is not included. I want to apply js on particular cms page.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this blog post and i hope that it will help you to solve your issues. You can also share your code what you have done so far.
https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_css_layout_woes/

Answer (score 0):

`<reference name="head"> 
   <action method="addJs"><script>megnor/carousel.min.js</script></action>
</reference>`

Comment: can you, please, add more information regarding this code. It will be more useful.